# manipulating contents of a text file

Tags: windows, editor, notepad++

Suppose I have made a text file in the following format:

```
1 4 4        
2 3 4        
2 431 431    
2 473 473    
4 44 44      
10  36 36      
20 34 34      
10 5 5        
5 5 2        
100 63 63      
110 112 112    
60 1327 1327  
70 75 75      
80 27 27      
60 14 14      
150  16 16      
200 129 129
```

Now I want to make a distance of a tab key between two different column values  as follows:

```
1   4    4        
2    3    4        
2    431    431    
2    473    473    
4    44    44      
10    36    36      
20    34    34      
10    5    5        
5    5    2        
100    63    63      
110    112    112    
60    1327    1327  
70    75    75      
80    27    27      
60    14    14      
150    16    16      
200    129   129
```

Is there any way of doing this at a time using any text editor or any other way?Also, if I want to delete an entire column at a time, how will I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You may use a regular expression that will match and capture digits, then will match 1 or more spaces, and then will match and capture digits again, then just replace the spaces with a tab. In Notepad++, use:

*Find What*: `(\d+) +(\d+)`
*Replace With*: `$1\t$2`

[image]

*Details*:

- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (later referred to with `$1` backreference from the replacement pattern): one or more digits
- `+` - one or more spaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 2 (later referred to with `$2` backreference from the replacement pattern): one or more digits

Comment: if I want to delete an entire column what will be the regular expression? @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: [*Column Mode Editing. Using Alt + Mouse dragging or. Alt + Shift + Arrow keys to switch to columnmode*](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html).